# Stuck with JSON parsing

Tags: zig

I have an http GET request that is returning the following JSON:

```
info: {
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*,application/json", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, zstd", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "zig/0.11.0 (std.http)", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-64f5fbff-5e155e853633a140652c0c95"
  }, 
  "origin": "188.248.195.218", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/get"
}
```

I'm trying to capture it with the below code:

```
const std = @import("std");
const http = std.http;

const Config = struct {
    info: struct {
        args: []const u8,
        headers: struct {
            Accept: []const u8,
            AcceptEncoding: []const u8,
            Host: []const u8,
            UserAgent: []const u8,
            XAmznTraceId: []const u8,
        },
        origin: []const u8,
        url: []const u8,
    },
};

pub fn main() !void {
    // Create an allocator.
    var gpa = std.heap.GeneralPurposeAllocator(.{}){};
    const allocator = gpa.allocator();

    // Create an HTTP client.
    var client = http.Client{ .allocator = allocator };
    // Release all associated resources with the client.
    defer client.deinit();

    // Parse the URI.
    const uri = std.Uri.parse("http://httpbin.org/get") catch unreachable;

    // Create the headers that will be sent to the server.
    var headers = std.http.Headers{ .allocator = allocator };
    defer headers.deinit();

    // Accept anything.
    try headers.append("accept", "*/*");
    try headers.append("accept", "application/json");

    // Make the connection to the server.
    var request = try client.request(.GET, uri, headers, .{});
    defer request.deinit();

    // Send the request and headers to the server.
    try request.start();

    // Wait for the server to send use a response.
    try request.wait();

    // Read the entire response body, but only allow it to allocate 8KB of memory.
    const body = request.reader().readAllAlloc(allocator, 8192) catch unreachable;
    defer allocator.free(body);

    // Print out the response.
    std.log.info("{s}", .{body});

    var json_reader = std.json.reader(allocator, request.reader());

    if (std.json.parseFromTokenSource(std.json.Value, allocator, &json_reader, .{})) |json| {
        std.log.info("json: {any}", .{json});
    } else |err| {
        std.log.err("error: {any}", .{err});
    }

    if (std.json.parseFromSlice(Config, allocator, body, .{})) |config| {
        defer config.deinit();
        std.log.info("json: {any}", .{config});
    } else |err| {
        std.log.err("error: {any}", .{err});
    }
}
```

And got the output as below, which means both of my approaches are wrong:

```
info: {
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*,application/json", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, zstd", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "zig/0.11.0 (std.http)", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-64f5fbff-5e155e853633a140652c0c95"
  }, 
  "origin": "188.248.195.218", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/get"
}

error: error: error.UnexpectedEndOfInput
error: error: error.UnknownField
```

Comment: I don't see why you use `catch unreachable` for `readAllAlloc`. Just use `try`.

Comment: Also, you're missing `defer gpa.deinit();`, but even better, use `defer std.debug.assert(gpa.deinit() == .ok);` to be notified of memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Config` struct is incorrect:

- `info` is not part of the struct, it is returned from `std.log.info`
- `args` is not a string in JSON
- For `Accept-Encoding`, `User-Agent` and `X-Amzn-Trace-Id` you need to use the [`@""` syntax](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#Identifiers)

For example, with this `Config` struct, `std.json.parseFromSlice` succeeds in parsing the JSON:

```
const Config = struct {
        args: struct {},
        headers: struct {
            Accept: []const u8,
            @"Accept-Encoding": []const u8,
            Host: []const u8,
            @"User-Agent": []const u8,
            @"X-Amzn-Trace-Id": []const u8,
        },
        origin: []const u8,
        url: []const u8,
};
```

So, a working code could be:

```
const std = @import("std");
const http = std.http;

const Config = struct {
    args: struct {},
    headers: struct {
        Accept: []const u8,
        @"Accept-Encoding": []const u8,
        Host: []const u8,
        @"User-Agent": []const u8,
        @"X-Amzn-Trace-Id": []const u8,
    },
    origin: []const u8,
    url: []const u8,
};

pub fn main() !void {
    // Create an allocator.
    var gpa = std.heap.GeneralPurposeAllocator(.{}){};
    const allocator = gpa.allocator();
    defer if (gpa.deinit() != .ok) {
        std.log.err("We got a leack", .{});
    } else {
        std.log.debug("memory managed correctly", .{});
    };

    // Create an HTTP client.
    var client = http.Client{ .allocator = allocator };
    // Release all associated resources with the client.
    defer client.deinit();

    // Parse the URI.
    const uri = std.Uri.parse("http://httpbin.org/get") catch unreachable;

    // Create the headers that will be sent to the server.
    var headers = std.http.Headers{ .allocator = allocator };
    defer headers.deinit();

    // Accept anything.
    try headers.append("accept", "*/*");
    try headers.append("accept", "application/json");

    // Make the connection to the server.
    var request = try client.request(.GET, uri, headers, .{});
    defer request.deinit();

    // Send the request and headers to the server.
    try request.start();

    // Wait for the server to send use a response.
    try request.wait();

    // Read the entire response body, but only allow it to allocate 8KB of memory.
    const body = request.reader().readAllAlloc(allocator, 8192) catch unreachable;
    defer allocator.free(body);

    // Print out the response.
    std.log.info("{s}", .{body});

    if (std.json.parseFromSlice(Config, allocator, body, .{})) |config| {
        defer config.deinit();
        std.log.info("url: {s}", .{config.value.url});
        std.log.info("host: {s}", .{config.value.headers.Host});
    } else |err| {
        std.log.err("error: {any}", .{err});
    }

    if (std.json.parseFromSlice(std.json.Value, allocator, body, .{})) |config| {
        defer config.deinit();
        std.log.info("url: {s}", .{config.value.object.get("url").?.string});
        std.log.info("host: {s}", .{config.value.object.get("headers").?.object.get("Host").?.string});
    } else |err| {
        std.log.err("error: {any}", .{err});
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
info: {
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*,application/json", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, zstd", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "zig/0.11.0 (std.http)", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-64f6075d-3774be99775b576713baed7c"
  }, 
  "origin": "188.248.195.218", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/get"
}

info: url: http://httpbin.org/get
info: host: httpbin.org
info: url: http://httpbin.org/get
info: host: httpbin.org
debug: memory managed correctly
```